# Printing contents of Ruby array

Tags: ruby

I would like to know why arrays will print content even if not told too. Here's an example because I'm bad at explaining.

```
    def connect(host)
    begin
        sock = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
        sockaddr = Socket.sockaddr_in(23, host)

        puts "Telnet available on #{host}\n" if sock.connect(sockaddr)

    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
        puts "Telnet unavailable on #{host}"
    end
end


def scan
    @host = str_r(@host) # Formats IP

        (1..255).each do |oct|
            begin
                nhost = @host+oct.to_s
                @array << connect(nhost)

            rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
                #puts "Host #{nhost} unreachable!"
            end
        end
    #puts @array
end
```

Where method loops does something like try to connect to a host. Even though I haven't told it to 'puts' anything, it does. It puts the results of method(p), one by one. What I'd rather have it do is save all the results into an array, and then print them all at the end once it's done trying to connect to all the hosts. Doesn't the '<<' operator simply add whatever into an array?

Comment: There is no printing code here. Maybe there is some printing going on inside that method.

Comment: Do you mean IRB? IRB always shows the return value of the code

Comment: Edited first post slightly. Even though there is printing inside the method, I still don't understand why it prints. I'm not actually calling the method, just pushing it into an array. Right? And no, it's not IRB.

Comment: @user3674736 It is indeed actually calling the method, what made you think it is not? Specifically, the method is being called with parameter `p`, and the return value of that method is pushed in to the array.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. The return value is pushed in to the array. So nothing should print until I call the array right?

Comment: @user3674736 So there's no `puts` or any kind of output statement at all in the `method` method, correct? And the array is a simple array object you declared using `array = {}` or `array = Array.new`? I know what you've written is a representation of your actual scenario, but can you show the actual code (including the `method` method), assuming its not too enormous?

Comment: Ok I edited the original code. The @array is an array declared earlier in the class(the code I posted is part of a class). I do have strings being printed in connect(), but I really don't understand why the print out even if I'm just pushing it all into and array.

Comment: The method `method` IS EXECUTED.  The executed method does `puts` statements, so they're going to happen.  If you want the statements that are `puts` to be stored for later output, then store them somewhere and then have some other process later `puts` them to your output device.  Basically, `puts` happen when `puts` happen, they don't get "suspended" for later execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the update, there are two issues:

1. You do indeed have some `puts` statements in the `connect` method which, given the flow of the method, will always output something, regardless.
2. In ruby, the last statement in a method is the value returned from that method. The `puts` method doesn't return anything, and `puts` is the last line of the method (even if it drops in to the rescue block). You can either try rewriting the method so the value you want is the last time (probably messy), or simply add `return [something]` at the end, to ensure the value you want is returned (where `[something]` is the variable to be returned).

Also, just to address your statement in the comments: *I really don't understand why the print out even if I'm just pushing it all into and array*.

The key thing to keep in mind is that those are two **separate** operations: First, the method is called...THEN the return value is pushed to the array. The method has no clue where its return value is going, so those `puts` statements are going to be executed regardless, unless you put something in the method to filter them (like an `if` statement, which you already have at least once, it looks like).

Comment: Thank you this seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user3674736 Cool, glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer (green checkmark to the left of the answer), whichever one helped you best.

Answer (score 2):

In the [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) it says that

> ary << obj → ary
>
> Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.

This is a syntactic sugar ; Others ways to write your code could be

- `@array.<<(connect(nhost))`
- `@array.send(:<<, connect(nhost))`

Your pushed object is given by the returned value of `connect(nhost)` **it is an argument of your push method.** (and is evaluated on method call as any other arguments).

If you do not want your method to be evaluated, you can use a Proc object like this :

```
(1..255).each do |oct|
  nhost = @host+oct.to_s
  array << -> { connect(nhost) }
  # same as
  # array.push(Proc.new { connect(nhost) })
end
```

And get Proc objects called later like this : `array[0].call` or `array.map &:call`

Answer (score 1):

the way it works in this code:

```
(1..20).each do |p|
    array << method(p)
end
```

1. The method `method(p)` is executed
2. The result of executing
           `method(p)` (the returned value) is appended to the array

If you would like to store the method for later evaluation, there are a few techniques you can use.  One simple one would be to store the method as a string...

```
(1..20).each do |p|
    array << 'method(p)'
end
```

... and later execute it using an `eval` statement..

```
eval array[0] # will evaluate the string in array[0] as ruby code.
```

You may also want to look up Procs and Lambdas which are a more flexible way to store program code in a variable.